# Hibernate wild card LIKE return only first item on table

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project i need to search book by its title..
The below code gives only th first item from the table not all item with same character

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Book b where str(b.name) like :title");
            query.setParameter("title",title+"%");
            books=query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add wildcard at the beginning.Currently,it shows the item from the table which begin from your parameter

```
 query.setParameter("title",("%" +title+"%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for case sensitive. Data in db is case sensitive. Use query like 
`("from Book b where upper(str(b.name)) like upper(:title"));` this will make your search case insensitive.

Comment: all datas are lower case